# C# Switch Statement with multiple ifs to Calculate a range of numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C# and am making a windows form in .net and am using the following switch statement where I am calculating the the BMI of candidates. After testing this program it will execute the first case, but then the following cases dont work.

Thank you for your help.
-Mike

*Where SwitchFinal is the calculated BMI, and Age being a variable holding the user inputed age*

```
  int switchvar = 1;
               switch (switchvar)
               {

                   case 1:
                    if (Age >= 17 && Age < 21 && SwitchFinal < 20)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Eligible!");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Not Eligible");
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (Age >= 21 && Age < 28 && SwitchFinal < 22)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Eligible!");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Not Eligible");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (Age >= 28 && Age <40 && SwitchFinal < 24)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Eligible!");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Not Eligible");
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    if (Age >= 40 &&  SwitchFinal < 24)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Eligible!");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Not Eligible");
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: How do you expect it to go anywhere else, if the value you 'switch' on is always 1...?

Comment: Not clear what you are expecting. You set `switchvar` to 1 and runs the 1 case... Do you actually know what a `switch` does? seems like you might just need some `if else if else if else ...`

Comment: Do you change your switchVar anywhere else ? It seems odd to use it in this situation.

Comment: Oh I see, this is my first time touching c# only using the select case statement in VB.Net. How would i format the switch then? Would it be a for loop or just specifying a range?

Comment: explain what you are actually trying to do. c# switch is identical to vb select case, so that doesnt help explain anyting

Comment: You needs to learn C# from a book or tutorial; it's too large to learn from trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be you have four data *use cases* and you need to detect all of them. That doesn't mean you need switch/case. Not all *use cases* correspond to a usage of `switch case`; in fact there is no reason to make that connection at all. You just need to check all four use cases with `if` expressions.

Your code should probably look more like this:

```
public bool IsEligible()
{
    if (Age >= 17 && Age < 21 && SwitchFinal < 20)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (Age >= 21 && Age < 28 && SwitchFinal < 22)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (Age >= 28 && Age <40 && SwitchFinal < 24)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (Age >= 40 &&  SwitchFinal < 24)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void ExampleUsage()
{
    bool ok = IsEligible();
    if (ok)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Eligible!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is not Eligible!");
    }
}
```

If you feel like being clever and writing the shortest code possible, you could also do something like this:

```
public bool IsEligible()
{
    if (Age < 17) return false;
    if (SwitchFinal < 20) return Age < 21; 
    if (SwitchFinal < 22) return Age < 28;
    if (SwitchFinal < 24) true;
    return false;
}
```

Or if you want something more extensible, define a list containing a series of functions to evaluate each case, and search for a match using LINQ:

```
//using System;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Collections.Generic;

List<Func<int,int,bool>> useCases = new List<Func<int,int,bool>>
{
    (age, switchFinal) =>  switchFinal < 20 && age >= 17 && age < 21,
    (age, switchFinal) =>  switchFinal < 22 && age >= 17 && age < 28,
    (age, switchFinal) =>  switchFinal < 24 && age >= 28 && age < 40,
    (age, switchFinal) =>  switchFinal < 24 && age >= 40
};

public bool IsEligble(int age, int switchFinal)
{
    return useCases.Where
    (
        func => func(age, switchFinal)
    )
    .Any();
}
```

If you actually need the case number for some reason, you can easily modify the above to return it. Then, to determine eligibility, check for a valid case number (nonzero).

```
private Dictionary<int, Func<int,int,bool>> useCases = new Dictionary<int,Func<int,int,bool>>
{
    { 1, (age, switchFinal) =>  (age >= 17 && age < 21 && switchFinal < 20) },
    { 2, (age, switchFinal) =>  (age >= 17 && age < 28 && switchFinal < 22) },
    { 3, (age, switchFinal) =>  (age >= 28 && age < 40 && switchFinal < 24) },
    { 4, (age, switchFinal) =>  (age >= 40 && switchFinal < 24) }
};

public int GetCaseNumber(int age, int switchFinal)
{
    return useCases
        .Where( entry => entry.Value(age, switchFinal) )
        .Select( entry => entry.Key )
        .OrderBy( a => a )
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

void ExampleUsage()
{
    var caseNumber = GetCaseNumber(int.Parse(this.txtAge.Text), int.Parse(this.txtSwitchFinal.Text));
    if (caseNumber == default(int))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are not eligble.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You are eligble under case {0}.", caseNumber));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far but it could still be a lot better. Consider for example rewriting the body of `IsEligible` as `if (Age < 17) return false; if (Age < 21) return SwitchFinal < 20; if (Age < 28) return SwitchFinal < 22; return SwitchFinal < 24;` Much shorter and simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: Nice demonstration of the using the Open/Close principle in your last two examples!

Answer (score 0):

The switch case setup is not really built for ranges, you need to convert your ranges prior to the switch case if you intend that effect, however, since you are required to do that in an if else statement, there isn't much use for the switch case after.

like:

```
int switchRange = 0;
if(Age >= 17 && Age < 21)
{ switchRange = 1}
if (Age >= 21 && Age < 28)
{ switchRange = 2}
if (Age >= 28 && Age < 40)
{ switchRange = 3}
if (Age >= 40)
{ switchRange = 4}

switch(switchRange)
{
   case 1:{
if(SwitchFinal < 20)
{

                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Eligible!");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Not Eligible");
                    }
break;}
case 2:{
if(SwitchFinal < 22)
{

                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Eligible!");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Not Eligible");
                    }
break;}
}
case 3: case 4:{
if(SwitchFinal < 24)
{

                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Eligible!");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Candidate is Not Eligible");
                    }
break;}
```

That is my best bet.

Comment: Thank you so much, I apologize for my lack of information. This solved my issue.

Comment: @DieselGV Please choose this as your accept answer if it is the one that answered your question, I get reputation points for it ;)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to iterate through each case correct? If so, a switch statement is a little odd here. But, you could enclose the entire switch statement in a for loop

```
for (switchvar = 1; switchvar <= 4; switchvar++) {//your code}
```